Visual FoxPro, ODBC INSERT statements
I am writing to a DBF file using a Visual FoxPro ODBC driver supplied by Microsoft. It is for a system that extends legacy support.
I can insert data to the table, but I have to run PACK and re-indexing commands on the indexes related to the dbf (i.e. INDEXONE.IDX, INDEXTWO.IDX, INDEXTHREE.IDX) in order for a VFP program to see the data that was inserted by the ODBC connection I am making.
I can autocommit the changes, and it's the same - I have to re-index on the VFP side to see the data in the VFP program. I made sure there is a CDX generated that has the indexes associated with it in Table Designer. Same result.
I'm trying to figure out why I can't get the indexing to happen when it's written. Can someone help based on this info?
I tried generating a CDX and it's not working as expected. I can see that the data was written to the DBF but it won't show in a VFP program until I run a re-index.

It is expected behavior. Old IDX indexes are need to be open for them to be updated during insertion. You can try reindexing afterwards using ExecScript(). However, since VFP6 there is no official VFP ODBC driver. You better use the OLEDB driver (VFPOLEDB).
